# How to change days off in youtrack Gantt chart

Tags: gantt-chart, youtrack

youtrack's Gantt chart is always dealing with Sat and sun as days off , as shown in the image:

[image: Gantt chart]

How to change this days so issues can be processed in it. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that is it possible by just clicking settings(the gear icon near your profile image) >> Time tracking, then define the workdays from this page, and it will be fixed everywhere in your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible. There're several related feature requests like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-38441 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-29883.